# How to register repository pattern under configure service on startup class

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

**How to register  Generic Repository pattern on startup class under configure service function ?**

I try to register repository pattern on configure service function on startup.cs as below but i get error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TabDataAccess.Repositories.RepositoryTab`1[TabDataAccess.Dto.Employee]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'WebTabCore.Controllers.EmployeeController'.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
    
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IrepositoryTab<>), typeof(RepositoryTab<>));
services.AddDbContext<TabDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            }
```

**Code details**

```
public class Employee   
{   
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }    
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }   
} 


 public class TabDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TabDbContext(DbContextOptions<TabDbContext> options)
: base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

public class RepositoryTab : IrepositoryTab where T : class   
{   
protected TabDbContext db { get; set; }   
private DbSet dbSet;  
public RepositoryTab(TabDbContext Tabdb)   
{              
db = Tabdb;              
dbSet = db.Set();   
}   
public IEnumerable GetAll()   
{  
 return dbSet.ToList();  
}   
}  

public interface IrepositoryTab where T : class
 {
 IEnumerable GetAll();        

 }
```

On EmployeeController

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
 {
    
    private readonly IrepositoryTab<Employee> _repository;
    public EmployeeController(RepositoryTab<Employee> emp)
    {
        this._repository = emp;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = _repository.GetAll();
        return View(employees);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You registered it in the service collection with:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IrepositoryTab<>), typeof(RepositoryTab<>));
```

Which quite literally means: "inject `RepositoryTab<>` whenever `IrepositoryTab<>` is requested." However, your controller takes `RepositoryTab<>` in its constructor, and there's no service registration for `RepositoryTab<>` itself. In other words, you need to change it to `IrepositoryTab<>` instead:

```
public EmployeeController(IrepositoryTab<Employee> emp)
```

Comment: it solved but i have small questions are using repository direct is good or doing interface for every model i using meaning use Iemployee and inherite from repository or using inheritance from repository direct

Comment: Best thing to do is not use repositories at all if you want to get down to the bass tacks of it. See: https://cpratt.co/repositories-and-entity-framework/